# Conditional lists with JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown list of "data" based on what "id" was selected. I get the data from a JSON response from a http request. The format is:

```
[
 { "id": 1, "data":[1,2,3,4] },

   { "id": 2, "data":[5,6,7] }
]
```

The html is:

```
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Ciudad</ion-label>
    <ion-select >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let undato of datosRecibidos">{{undato.nombre}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Fracción</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option [?????] </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

The .ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ServicioPost]
})
export class HomePage {
  datosRecibidos: Datos[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private unservicio: ServicioPost ) {
    this.unservicio.getdatos('mc').subscribe(datos_recibidos => 
     this.datosRecibidos=datos_recibidos);
  }
}
interface Datos {
  id: string;
  data: string[];
}
```

So I want to make a dropdown list based on the selection of id in a previous selection. How can I populate this? I'm trying to do it with *ngFor but can't realise how to do that. I'm new to Angular2 and TypeScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

in html

```
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Ciudad</ion-label>
    <ion-select (change) = "selectId($event)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let undato of datosRecibidos" [value] = "undato.id">{{undato.id}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Fracción</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let item of selectItems ">{{item}}  </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

in .ts file

```
    export class HomePage {
      datosRecibidos: Datos[];

      selectItems:any = [];
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private unservicio: ServicioPost ) {
          this.unservicio.getdatos('mc').subscribe((datos_recibidos) => {
          this.datosRecibidos=datos_recibidos;
          this.selectItems = datos_recibidos[0]['data'];
          )};
       }


       selectId(event:any){
           let selectedId = event.target.value;
           for(let i = 0 ; i < this.datosRecibidos.length ; i++){
                if(selectedId === this.datosRecibidos[i]['id']){
                   this.selectItems = this.datosRecibidos[i]['data'];
                }
           }

       }

    }
    interface Datos {
      id: string;
      data: string[];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @vikash. Actually your code needed two minor modifications. 1) the event in ionic is ionChange for that component. The second is the iteration within the for which is length-1. The code below works. Thanks for your contribution

```
<ion-select (ionChange) = "selectId($event)">
```

in .ts:

```
for ( let i=0; i<=this.datosRecibidos.length-1; i++ ){
```